# Why the `fake()->dateTimeBetween` is not working as expected?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, faker

In my factory seeder i'm using this code.
but it's not working as expected, and the results are with random (up to one month) difference.
Why?

```
$start = fake()->dateTimeThisMonth();
$end = fake()->dateTimeBetween($start, '+1 day');
```

Up to one day difference, when the `$start` is the min'

Comment: `$start` and `$_start` are not the same thing.

Comment: @ceejayoz ooops :) i played with the code, and copied the wrong var. fixing. thanks

Comment: you didn't write what you expect.

Comment: @dlnsk i'm trying to get two dates with 1 day difference. however, the difference is up to one month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ordinary DateTime class

```
$start = fake()->dateTimeThisMonth();
$end = (clone $start)->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
```

Comment: I accept, even tho it's not using the `fake()` object, since it's working and no one else answered. thanks!